# Compile error when using activemq and <mman.h>

Tags: c++, activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

On my ubuntu system, I write the code that using activemq-cpp 3.6.0 and mman.h and there is a tricky compile error.

I write a very simple code to verify this problem:

```
  #include <sys/mman.h>
  #include <activemq/core/ActiveMQConnection.h>

  int main(int argc, char** argv)
  {
      return 0;
  }
```

And here is the compile error message:

```
g++ -c -O2 -D_INTEL686 -D_LINUX -I. -I.. -I/home/matt/devspace/trading-apps/../trading-dependency/activemq-cpp/include/activemq-cpp-3.6.0 -I/home/matt/devspace/trading-apps/../trading-dependency/apr/include/apr-1  mqtest.cpp -o mqtest.o
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/mman.h:41:0,
                 from mqtest.cpp:2:
/home/matt/devspace/trading-apps/../trading-dependency/activemq-cpp/include/activemq-cpp-3.6.0/activemq/util/PrimitiveValueNode.h:56:13: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
             MAP_TYPE           = 11,
```

If I put the "mman.h" after "activemq/core/ActiveMQConnection.h", it will be OK.
Anyone have the same problem?

**======UPDATE ON 2015/1/7===========================================**

I have a further investigation on this issue.
In "bits/mmap.h":

```
# define MAP_TYPE   0x0f        /* Mask for type of mapping.  */
```

In "activemq/util/PrimitiveValueNode.h":

```
enum PrimitiveType {
    ...,
    MAP_TYPE           = 11,
    ...
}
```

Here is the conflict. So the "PrimitiveValueNode.h" must be included before "mman.h".

I think this is the typical scenario to show why we SHOULD NOT use #define in C/C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most probably related to conflict of some defines or global declaration. If something was defined in mman.h and same string/name was used later in second header it may cause such error. Changing the order of include helps because of the way how compilation unit is builded - problematic define is later. I had situation like this many times, but with different headers.

Comment: I agree with you. I just can not believe the "activemq" conflict with "mman.h". It is such a widely used library.